# Swing java, window split with content in both halves

Tags: java, windows, swing, text-files

I am trying to write a program with Java using Swing that will display a window as such:

```
   +--------------+-----------------------------------+
   |              |                                   |
   |              |                                   |
   |              |                                   |
   |              |                                   |
   |              |                                   |
   |              |                                   |
   |              |                                   |
   +--------------+-----------------------------------+
```

With the left window having text files, and the right window loading the text files. The problem is two-fold. For one, Swing is giving me mental fits, as I cannot seem to understand how splitting a frame works.

The second half of the problem is that when I get text in the right side, its just randomly places and has white space around it. I want it to display like a windows explorer window, but the text formatted more like a text viewer, if that makes sense.

Here is what I have tried.

```
package myCB;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MyCB extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new MyCB();

}

public MyCB() {

    super("MyCB.0.0.0.1");
    setResizable(true);
    setSize(750, 400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//      Dimension size1 = new Dimension(200, 400);
//      Dimension size2 = new Dimension(500, 400);      

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JPanel b1 = new JPanel();
    b1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 400));
    JPanel b2 = new JPanel();
    b2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

    b1.setVisible(true);
    b2.setVisible(true);

    JTextArea text = new JTextArea("This is a sample of a text area" + "in Java Swing for my program.");
    text.setLineWrap(true);
    text.setWrapStyleWord(true);


    b2.add(text);

    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setVisible(true);

    p.add(b1, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    p.add(b2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    p.setVisible(true);
    repaint();

    add(p);
    revalidate();

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been struggling with Swing for weeks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a small example for you, try to inspire for it

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class SplitPane extends JFrame {

    private JPanel p1 = new JPanel(), p2 = new JPanel();
    private JSplitPane jsp;
    public SplitPane() {
        super("SplitPane example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p1.setBackground(Color.orange);

        p2.setBackground(Color.green);

        jsp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, true, p1, p2);
        jsp.setDividerLocation(getWidth() / 2);
        setContentPane(jsp);

        setSize(300, 300);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SplitPane();
    }

}
```

Hope that helps, if so make up please =) Salam

Answer (score 0):

> I have been struggling with Swing for weeks.

Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are plenty of working examples there to get you started.

There are plenty of issues with your code:

1. Don't use setPreferredSize(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Then the layout manager will determine the appropriate size for each component. Read the tutorial section on `layout managers`
2. A JTextArea should be displayed in a JScrollPane and then the scroll pane added to the panel. You may want to create you text area using new JTextArea(5, 30), to give a hint for the preferred size of the text area. Read the tutorial section on `text component features`
3. You should only invoke the `setVisible()` method of the frame AFTER all components have been added to the frame. When you do this there is no need to invoke repaint() or revalidate(). Also, you should invoke `pack()` just before the setVisible() so all component are displayed at their preferred sizes.
4. GUI components should be created on the Event Dispatch Thread. Read the section on `Concurrency`.

> its just randomly places and has white space around it.

This is normal. When you add a component to the CENTER, it occupies all the remaining available space on the frame.

> but the text formatted more like a text viewer, if that makes sense.

Doesn't make sense to me. A text area is just like the area you where you typed your question into on this forum.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I started with Oracles tutorials, then I got lost. Thanks again!

Comment: @phyremynd, what do you mean you got lost? Your code looks nothing like the code from the tutorial examples. That is why you got lost. The point of the tutorial is to start with something that works and then customize it for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should start reading on the different swing layouts helping you organize the space without manually setting the sizes yourself. There are many examples on the different layouts on [The Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

You can see examples to do exactly what you want to have as a result [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html): You set the FlowLayout and then set the preferred size for the left panel. The size of the left one is automatically set, based on the size of the window.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I started using the Java Tutorial, but it got confusing without guided help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a JSplitPane. It's very easy too use, you simple specify the orientation (Horizantal or Vertical) and you can either use two JPanels or other containers/components. Anyway here is a simple example:

```
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, rightPanel);

        JLabel lblRight = new JLabel("Right");
        rightPanel.add(lblRight);

        JLabel lblLeft = new JLabel("Left");
        leftPanel.add(lblLeft);
```

And since you said you've been struggling with swing for such a long time have you tried the [windowbuilder plugin?](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)